# Old WordPress pagination URLs still show first page of content and Google indexes some of them

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, pagination

We use self-hosted Wordpress and earlier we were using paginated posts in our article like.

```
www.example.com/some-article.html
www.example.com/some-article.html/2
www.example.com/some-article.html/3
```

Now even after we have removed pagination, the
`www.example.com/some-article.html/2` and `www.example.com/some-article.html/3` 
URLs are still opening with same full content as is on `www.example.com/some-article.html`.

And I find Google is still indexing several of those paginated URLs, despite the canonical URL on those 2 paginated URLs rightly pointing to `www.example.com/some-article.html`.

I think maybe it's because several bloggers have linked to us using our old paginated urls `/2` and `/3` and Google is still following those links.

Can someone provide me a solution, either via `.htaccess` code or functions so that if someone opens `www.example.com/some-article.html/2` or `www.example.com/some-article.html/3` they get redirected to `www.example.com/some-article.html`.

or if that's not possible then at least if someone opens `www.example.com/some-article.html/2` or `www.example.com/some-article.html/3` then it gives 404 Not Found error.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Current `.htaccess` code is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect these URLs, you can do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front-controller:

```
RewriteRule ^(some-article\.html)/ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This checks for `/some-article.html` followed by a slash (and optionally anything else). And redirects to `/some-article.html` (the value of the `$1` backreference). The `$1` backreference simply saves typing/duplication (and in doing so lessens the chance of introducing errors).

To be more specific and match only `/some-article.html/N` (where `N` is any digit) then change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to `^(some-article\.html)/\d`. Or to match just the specific URLs you mentioned (ie. `/2` or `/3`) then use `^(some-article\.html)/[23]` instead.

NB: First test with a 302 (temporary) and only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect when you are sure it's working OK.

> google is still indexing several of those paginated urls, inspite canonical url on those 2 paginated urls

Google still indexes non-canonical URLs, it's just that they shouldn't normally appear in organic search results. A `site:` search is not a normal search (if that is what you are using to check for indexed URLs) and often returns non-canonical and even redirected URLs.

**UPDATE#1:**

> ...we have to fix this problem with about 500 articles

Then you can probably just generalise the regex, if your URLs end in `.html` and you want to redirect *all* previously paginated URLs. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+\.html)/\d /$1 [R=301,L]
```

`\w` is a shorthand character class that matches any *word* character. ie. `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`. I've also included a hyphen in the encompassing character class.

---

**UPDATE#2:**

It seems (having discussed this in chat) that the actual URLs you are requesting contain an additional path-segment (a WordPress "category") of the form: `/<category>/<article>.html`. So you will need to modify the above directive to something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/[\w-]+\.html)/\d /$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

> ```
> # BEGIN WordPress
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> # Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
> # END WordPress
> ```

Note that you should avoid modifying the directives inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` section - this is maintain by WordPress (or at least it tries to), so any modifications you make might be overridden later.

Your custom directives should go *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section.

For example:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect old paginated URLs
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/[\w-]+\.html)/\d /$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

You do not *need* to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive (although it's not necessarily an "error" to do so). The *last* `RewriteEngine` directive takes priority and controls the entire file, so earlier `RewriteEngine` directives are effectively ignored.

Comment: Actually, we have to fix this problem with about 500 articles so it won't be possible to put all those 500 urls in htaccess. Need the code some other way!

Comment: or may be if someway we can auto-add  noindex, nofollow to all pages which have /2  or /3 in url.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a more generic solution to match "any" article. This assumes all URLs are at the root (no other path segments). Presumably all these `.html` URLs are handled by WP?

Comment: Ok I added the code in my htaccess but it didn't worked..when I open urls with /2 or /3 its opening same like earlier..not redirecting. Here is my htaccess code..do note that it also contains http to https redirect code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97055/discussion-between-samjoezzy-and-mrwhite).

Comment: Thanks, Mrwhite the code you provided is working awesome.
You are a real genius.
And thanks for the additional help about where to put the http to https redirect code.